# Where do I find treaties/acts granting French colonies independence?

Tags: independence, vietnam, french-empire

I am a History student researching on the history of Indo-China and African countries that were under French colonial rule. I did not find certain treaties like Franco-Lao treaty and others on the internet. Could someone guide me on where I could possibly find them on the internet.

Comment: It probably helps to phrase the question in French, the language of these documents.

Comment: you can probably find it at journal-officiel.gouv.fr or diplomatie.gouv.fr

Comment: There is a database of all treaties to which France is party on the [website of the French foreign ministry](http://basedoc.diplomatie.gouv.fr/Traites/Accords_Traites.php). If you look for a given country around the time of its independence, you will typically find a string of agreements regulating its membership in the “communauté française” and some transitory measures.

Answer (score 1):

They're scattered all over the internet. For example the Evian Accords for Algeria:

[Link](http://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/afrique/algerie-accords_d'Evian.htm)

A large number of colonies simply voted to be independent:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_constitutional_referendum,_1958

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afars_and_Issas_independence_referendum,_1977

Generally, an independence document is only needed if independence comes as part of a peace treaty at a conclusion of a war, when there are two parties to negotiate the terms. There is probably too much involved in setting up an independent government from scratch for a single document to be useful. And if the government has already reported the results of a referendum, anything further is unnecessary.